# How do I implement SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS on a query with UNION?

Tags: mysql, count

Mysql, I am using SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS to get the total number of possible records.
How do I use it on UNION?
The only thing that works for me right now, which seems somewhat off is:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM(SELECT * FROM t1 UNION SELECT * FROM t2) A;
```

or

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS *
FROM(SELECT * FROM t1 UNION SELECT * FROM t2) A;
```

Comment: whats wrong with your solutions?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

From the [FOUND_ROWS() documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows):

> The use of SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS and
>   FOUND_ROWS() is more complex for UNION
>   statements than for simple SELECT
>   statements, because LIMIT may occur at
>   multiple places in a UNION. It may be
>   applied to individual SELECT
>   statements in the UNION, or global to
>   the UNION result as a whole.
>
> The intent of SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS for
>   UNION is that it should return the row
>   count that would be returned without a
>   global LIMIT. The conditions for use
>   of SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS with UNION are:
>
> - The SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS keyword must
>     appear in the first SELECT of the
>     UNION.
> - The value of FOUND_ROWS() is exact
>     only if UNION ALL is used. If UNION
>     without ALL is used, duplicate removal
>     occurs and the value of FOUND_ROWS()
>     is only approximate.
> - If no LIMIT is present in the UNION,
>     SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS is ignored and
>     returns the number of rows in the
>     temporary table that is created to
>     process the UNION.

Comment: Just to clarify, it's `SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM ((SELECT columns FROM t1) UNION ALL (SELECT columns FROM t2)) _ut` *not* `SELECT * FROM ((SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS columns FROM t1) UNION ALL (SELECT columns FROM t2)) _ut`

Answer (score 5):

You must specify `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` on the first `SELECT` in the `UNION` only; you don't actually need an outer `SELECT` query as you do when using `COUNT(*)`.

By way of example, let's say we have the following `LIMIT`ed query:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table1 
UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM my_table2 
UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM my_table3
LIMIT 0,10;
```

We can simply write:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM my_table1 
UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM my_table2 
UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM my_table3
LIMIT 0,10;
```

We then call:

```
SELECT FOUND_ROWS();
```

This avoids some overhead of having the outer query mentioned in your question and in the comments of Joe Stefanelli's answer (although I'm not entirely convinced it would be a noticeable difference).

I think it's worth re-iterating that this **will only work if you are using `UNION ALL` rather than `UNION`** - This is because the row count is calculated before duplicates are removed, meaning you'll get the same result from `FOUND_ROWS()` as you would if you had used `UNION ALL`.